# Akka I/O 2.2 Server initiated TCP client connection never transmits anything

Tags: scala, akka

I have a akka i/o TCP Server which on client connect should be initiating a further (client-)connection to another server.

[image: setup]

The approach that I wanted to go is -> TCP Actor -> Listen -> For each successful connection initiate a new client-actor and then pass all the communication between peers

Handling the client on the TCP Server works alright. But whenever I initiate another actor for the connect to the second server the connection can be setup but never responds, eventually it runs into

```
case _: ConnectionClosed ⇒ context stop self;
```

I have a hard time getting into it, as there is not much explicit documentation online. My client mostly represents the client example from the docs.

(the listener parameter is the client-server actor.)

```
class ClientTransProxyHandler(remote: InetSocketAddress, listener: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  IO(Tcp) ! Connect(remote)

  def receive = {
    case CommandFailed(_: Connect) ⇒
      listener ! "failed"
      context stop self

    case c @ Connected(remote, local) ⇒
      val connection = sender
      connection ! Register(self)
      context become {
        case data: ByteString ⇒
          connection ! Write(data);
        case CommandFailed(w: Write) ⇒ // O/S buffer was full
        case Received(data) ⇒
          listener ! data; println(data); 
        case "close" ⇒
          connection ! Close; 
        case _: ConnectionClosed ⇒ context stop self;
      }
  }
}
```

Connection seems to be initiated as I get into the become routine. But it never sends anything when I do the

```
client ! data  // where data is what i got initially from the client
```

I'm not even sure if this ever gets sent at all.

Thank You!

Full source can be found at https://github.com/AlessandroEmm/SNIProxy/blob/master/src/main/scala/SNIProxy/SNIProxy.scala

Comment: Take a look at spray-io and spray-can

Comment: @AlexIv doesn't spray operate on a higher level (HTTP and stuff)?

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to be answered: the code which is shown looks correct, but it is only a part of the relevant program. Have you verified that data are actually received and then forwarded by the `listener`?

Comment: @RolandKuhn as you may have noticed, its the basically the same question as on the akka user list. So the same source can be used. I'm currently trying to get the unhandled messages to be logged.

Comment: For the record, I added the link to the full source file.